# How to replace torch.norm with other pytorch function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I would like to replace the `torch.norm` function using the other Pytorch function.

I was able to replace `torch.norm` in the case where `x` is not a matrix, as shown in the following code.

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(9)
out1 = torch.norm(x)
out2 = sum(abs(x)**2)**(1./2)
out1 == out2
>> tensor(True)
```

But I don't know how to replace it when x is a matrix.
Especially, I want to replace it in my case of `dim=1 and keepdim=True`.

```
x = torch.randn([3, 136, 64, 64])
out1 = torch.norm(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
out2 = ???
out1 == out2
```

Background:

I'm converting a Pytorch model to CoreML, but the `_VF.frobenius_norm` operator defined in the `torch.norm` function is not implemented with CoreMLTools.
(The implementation inside `torch.norm` can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/functional.html#norm).)

A few people have trouble with this problem, but CoreMLTools is still unsupported (You can check from this [issue](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1000)).
So I'd like to replace it without the operator used in `torch.norm`.

I have tried `torch.linalg.norm()` and `numpy.linalg.norm` but they were not supported.

I have created a simple colaboratory notebook that reproduces this.
Please test it using the following colab.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11o6rTxHzEgZ_Rc7nFZHd3TvPugybB88h?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import torch
x = torch.randn([3, 136, 64, 64])
out1 = torch.norm(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
out2 = torch.square(x).sum(dim=1, keepdim=True).sqrt()
```

Note that `out1 == out2` won't give exactly all `True` due to small errors in precision. You can check that the errors are in the order of `1e-7` for `float32`.

Here, the norm is computed directly using its mathematical definition. You can see [this reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) from Wolfram MathWorld for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it only works with pytorch.
Unfortunately, `torch.diag` is not implemented in coremltools.
I updated the colab and I added your code in the `Answer from GoodDeeds` section.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11o6rTxHzEgZ_Rc7nFZHd3TvPugybB88h?usp=sharing#scrollTo=4IU0bvhqpGMp

Is it possible to implement this without `torch.diag`?

Comment: @tommy19970714 Unfortunately I cannot run colab right now, but I have updated my answer with a slightly better version, that avoids a lot of needless computations and the use of `torch.diag`. Please check if it works.

Comment: @tommy19970714 On a second look, I simplified it further. `torch.square(x)` is a bit new, and can be replaced with `torch.mul(x, x)` if not supported.

Comment: I checked your latest code. It works very well!
There are errors of e-06, but it is no problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @tommy19970714 Good to know. I just made one last edit a few seconds ago, to make the code more idiomatic.